Calculating confidence intervals with a change in the instrument
In an instrumental variable study, I have the point estimate of the outcome (a health outcome) and the corresponding confidence interval. I also have the mean of the instrument and the range (number of health worker visits in a year in a given population). I have to calculate how the confidence interval would change given a change in the instrument. That is, how the health outcome would change if the number of visits by the health worker changed. Can someone please guide me on how I can calculate this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
